# Rendering partials in haml and passing variable to it

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm trying to render my partials by iterating through variables and then pass specific variable to the partial but it doesn't see this variable.

Here I'm rendering it

(dogs.html.haml)

```
- dogs.each do |dog|
    .dog
      = render 'dog', :locals => { :dog => dog }
```

And then I want variable dog to be visible in my partial

(_dog.html.haml)

```
.title
  = dog.name
```

But it's not visible

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing together two different ways of rendering partials.

Use either this (legacy) form...

```
render partial: 'dog', locals: {dog: dog}
```

**or** this newer form:

```
render 'dog', dog: dog
```

**or** this *even better* newer form, which you should prefer:

```
= render dog
```

but not the version you've written. You've taken the `render 'dog'` part from the second way, and the `locals: { dog: dog }` part from the first way. That  passes a single local called `locals`, which has a value of a hash.

The third way is the preferred way. If you have an ActiveModel object, you can simply call `render <object>` and it will *automatically* choose the right partial for you based on the name of the model.

This works for collections of ActiveRecord models as well. You should be dropping your `@dogs.each` loop completely, and simply be calling

```
= render @dogs
```

This will *automatically* invoke `= render dog` for every dog in the collection. You just need to move your `.dog` inside the `_dog` partial.

Comment: You can also render the collection with `= render partial: "dog", collection: @dogs` which will automatically create a `dog` local variable for you [(relevant docs)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+a+collection+of+partials)

Comment: @etdev Again, that's a dated way that you should avoid. The better way is to simply `= render @dogs`, which is the new and functionally identical way.

Comment: @user229044 Incorrect. Rendering with an explicit `partial` is the preferred approach for Hotwire in Rails 7+

Comment: @Charlie You'll notice this question is tagged Rails 3/4, so it was and is correct.